# regsub 1 space between words to "_"

Tags: tcl

Can anyone help to regsub 1 space between words to "_" (TCL)?

The original line:

```
CTS__94331/I (DCCKBD8BWP240H11P57PDULVT)     0.025      0.002 &    0.352 r
```

The require line:

```
CTS__94331/I_(DCCKBD8BWP240H11P57PDULVT)     0.025      0.002_&    0.352_r
```

I tried the below but each space replaced to "*" and I want only 1 space to replace to "*"

```
regsub -all {\s{1}} $a _
```

Comment: remove `-all`? also are you sure your original/required lines are correct? It doesn't seem possible to get your required line if you only replace spaces from the original line...

Comment: This is definitely harder than it looks at first. But hiding critical cases off the edge of the page was a little unfair as it was a touch easy to miss; I reduced the width of long stretches of spaces to something that gives an equivalent problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be sneakier in your regular expression and use a different replacement.

```
regsub -all {(\S)\s(?=\S)} $a {\1_}
```

The regular expression matches (and captures) a non-whitespace followed by a whitespace and then requires (with a lookahead constraint) that the next character is a non-whitespace without matching it. This is replaced with the first character you matched (replacing it with itself) and the underscore.

---

Normally for this sort of thing you'd use `\y\s\y` → `_`, but that doesn't work in your use case because it doesn't handle `0.002 &` correctly (`&` is not a word character).

If Tcl's RE engine supported lookbehind constraints (it doesn't) this would be much simpler to solve as you wouldn't need the trickery of replacing the character before the space with itself.

Answer (score 0):

> regsub 1 space between words to "_"

For this case, you may consider `string map`:

```
% string map {" " "_"} {CTS__94331/I (DCCKBD8BWP240H11P57PDULVT)}
CTS__94331/I_(DCCKBD8BWP240H11P57PDULVT)
```

However, your example data is inconsistent and I do not see an example of more than one whitespace to be come replaced?

Comment: This will replace all spaces to "_" and I want to replace only 1 space between any characters.